# Rename files on SMB using smbj fails

Tags: java, smbj

I'm strugging to rename files *with* content to SMB using `com.hierynomus.smbj`.
Files are generated with content, but after renaming content is gone.

Following implementation renames files:

```
    public void rename(String pathFrom, String pathTo) {
        pathFrom = formatPath(pathFrom);
        pathTo = formatPath(pathTo);
        Set<SMB2ShareAccess> shareAccessSet = new HashSet<>();
        shareAccessSet.add(SMB2ShareAccess.FILE_SHARE_READ);
        shareAccessSet.add(SMB2ShareAccess.FILE_SHARE_WRITE);
        shareAccessSet.add(SMB2ShareAccess.FILE_SHARE_DELETE);

        Set<FileAttributes> fileAttributes = new HashSet<>();
        fileAttributes.add(FileAttributes.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
        Set<SMB2CreateOptions> createOptions = new HashSet<>();
        SMB2CreateDisposition smb2CreateDisposition = SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_OVERWRITE_IF;

        if (isFolder(pathFrom)) {
            createOptions.add(SMB2CreateOptions.FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE);
            smb2CreateDisposition = SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_OPEN_IF;
        }
        else if (isFile(pathFrom)) {
            createOptions.add(SMB2CreateOptions.FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE);
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Path '" + pathFrom + "' can't be resolved to file nor directory");
        }
        try (DiskEntry file = this.smbShare.open(pathFrom, of(AccessMask.MAXIMUM_ALLOWED), fileAttributes, shareAccessSet,
                smb2CreateDisposition, createOptions)) {
            file.rename(pathTo, true);
        }
    }
```

Maybe I messed up the attributes and options in `smbShare.open`-function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm.. I messed up with properties of `SMB2CreateDisposition`.

The solution: `smb2CreateDisposition = SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_OPEN_IF;`
instead of `smb2CreateDisposition = SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_OVERWRITE_IF;`

The former opens (1.) or creates (2.) the file in question.
The latter overwrites the existing file.